# navigate from redux action file without held state in redux?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I want to navigate from my reducx action file.For examble if user's session is expired i want to navigate to login screen

**please note that I am not using 'react-navigation-redux-helpers' for held navigation state in Redux**

let me know is it possible to navigate from action file without using redux -helper?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why can't you just redirect user from action itself from Redux?

Answer (score 0):

pass a callback from the component where you can access the router props to the action and redirect from there